# RefineryCMS Issue for Rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, refinerycms

I am trying to make a new apps using RefineryCMS on Rails 5.

```
"rails new getjob -m http://refinerycms.com/t/3-0-stable -d mysql"     

Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    refinerycms (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.0, >= 4.2.3)
        rake    db:create
Could not find gem 'refinerycms (~> 3.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    generate    refinery:cms --fresh-installation new getjob -m http://refinerycms.com/t/3-0-stable -d mysql
Could not find gem 'refinerycms (~> 3.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

    Your new Refinery CMS application is now installed and mounts at'/'

         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

    refinerycms (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.0, >= 4.2.3)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not find gem 'refinerycms (~> 3.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: you might want to check updates on this PR https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/pull/3122

Comment: No i am trying to create one apps on rails 5 "rails new getjob -m http://refinerycms.com/t/3-0-stable -d mysql"

Comment: 3-0-stable branch is not compatible with rails 5, please try this PR https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/pull/3122 like @Nimir said and report any bugs, thanks!